# Android - take picture - pass uri to camera app

Tags: android, android-camera, uri, android-camera-intent

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Camera) to invoke the camera app and ask it to save a picture at the uri passed in the intent.

```
 File image = File.createTempFile("testImage", ".jpg",
              getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));

 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(image);

 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

 if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(i, 1);
 }
```

The path of the image is :

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.test1.app/files/Pictures/testImage-516714791.jpg
```

I want to ask that how did the camera app have permission to write to this path ? I am testing on Android 4.4, so the path `ExternalFilesDir` is not publicly writable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) says:

> There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.
>
> Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application. To access paths belonging to other packages, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.

So, system Camera app, or any other app which is granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission can write to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.test1.app/files/Pictures/`.